# Search and highlight the search string in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My requirement is to search a kendo grid and highlight all the occurrence of the search string in yellow color in some specific columns in the grid. How can i done this without any other jquery plugins. I'm thinking like I have to find the table where the data displayed in grid and get the table by some class name and iterate the tr>td and get HTML and replace the text.

I have done this, 'English_Description_LongDesc' is the field name of my grid

```
var value = searchText;
var grid = $('#myKendoGrid').data('kendoGrid');
var columnFullText = "";
for (var index = 0; index < grid._data.length; index++) {

 columnFullText = grid._data[index]['English_Description_LongDesc'];
   //case-insensitive search
    if (columnFullText.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
       //Here I want to get the 'English_Description_LongDesc' cell HTML and highlight the search string 
   }
}
```

My thinking goes like I have to get the data from kendo grid and get the corresponding column data and search in the data and if a match then get the HTML and replace the column HTML.

Is this the right approach? Is there any better way to do this? **I'm very much new to kendo controls.**

---

As per Gene R solution. I am doing like this

```
var value = searchText;
var grid = $("#myKendoGrid").data('kendoGrid');   
var regex = new RegExp(value,"gi");
var colIndex = grid.thead.find("th[data-field='English_Description_LongDesc']").index();
var td = $(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')');
var item = grid.dataItem(this);
if (item.English_Description_LongDesc.indexOf(value) > -1) {
    td.html(item.English_Description_LongDesc.replace(regex, function (t) { return '<span class="highlight">' + t + '</span>'; }));
    }
```

But there is one issue with this. It become case sensitive highlight. If i search 'Apple' in the string 'APPLE TREE' it wont highlight. Any Ideas.

---

Its working fine. 
changed `if (item.English_Description_LongDesc.indexOf(value) > -1) {`
to `if (item.English_Description_LongDesc.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {`

---

**MORE REQUIREMENT**

Can we highlight all the search term given as input in a comma separated format using the same regex?
Eg: search input is 'apple,Orange,GRAPES'.  We have to highlight apple or Orange or GRAPES in the grid. 
  **I never understand the regex expressions. Its so hard for me**..

---

**UPDATE - Done comma separated search**
Here is my final code

```
var grid = $("#myKendoGrid").data('kendoGrid');   
var searchParts = searchText.split(",");
var regex = new RegExp(searchParts.join("|"), "gi");

grid.tbody.find('tr[data-uid]').each(function () {
     var colIndex = grid.thead.find("th[data-field='English_Description_LongDesc']").index();
     var td = $(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')');
     var item = grid.dataItem(this);
     if (regex.test(item.English_Description_LongDesc)) {
        td.html(item.English_Description_LongDesc.replace(regex, function (t) {
        return '<span class="highlight">' + t + '</span>';
        }));
     }
```

Comment: `if (item.English_Description_LongDesc.indexOf(value) > -1) {` is case sensitive

Comment: Yes. Thanks.. My mistake..

Comment: Can we highlight multiple search item separated by comma as input? Please see the updated question.

Comment: replace `,` with `|` : `apple|Orange|GRAPES`

Comment: I change it like this? is this enough. 
 var regex = new RegExp(value.split(",").join("|"), "gi");
tested this but not getting highlight

Comment: i bet problem is here `if (item.English_Description_LongDesc.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {`

Comment: it will work. i have to trim the spaces before and after comma

Comment: It works .. Great.... Thanks

Comment: Can we replace (item.English_Description_LongDesc.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) { with some regex to check if any of the search keywords contains in the string or not?

Comment: well, you can remove it, this `if` is not needed

Comment: I have to, I'm expanding the cell if it contains the string. else all cell get expand

Comment: if (regex.test(item.English_Description_LongDesc)) {   do the trick. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var value = searchText;
var grid = $("#myKendoGrid").data('kendoGrid');
var colIndex = grid.thead.find("th[data-field='English_Description_LongDesc']").index();   
var regex = new RegExp(value,"gi");

grid.tbody.find('tr[data-uid]').each(function(){
    var td = $(this).find('td:eq('+colIndex+')');
    var item = grid.dataItem(this);
    td.html(item.English_Description_LongDesc.replace(regex, '<span style="background-color:yellow">'+value+'</span>'));
});
```

**Update:** case insensitive highlight

here is working example: http://dojo.telerik.com/OraVA

**Update 2:** use this way if do not want to replace with `value`:

```
td.html(item.English_Description_LongDesc.replace(regex, function(t){
    return '<span style="background-color:yellow">'+t+'</span>';
}));
```

example: http://dojo.telerik.com/OraVA/5

Comment: its not highlighting. I have to highlight the exact search word (eg: highlight 'apple' in tr text 'apple tree')
$(this).find('td:eq('+colIndex+')') get the corresponding tr. and and we have to get the text of tr and highlight the exact word

Comment: I have a highlight class. can we do something like this? $(this).find('td:eq(' + colIndex + ')').text().replace(value, '<span class="highlight">' + value + '</span>')
 i tried like this..but not working

Comment: It is working perfectly. Just a minor problem. if then text is 'APPLE TREE' and we search with lowercase 'apple' the final output is 'apple TREE' . the original text case is replaced by search text case

Comment: Is Update 2 case sensitive ? How can i change it to case insensitive ?

Comment: I am using update 2. but when i search with a word, say 'Apple' in 'APPLE TREE' , it wont work. It only highlight when we search with case 'APPLE' @Gene